# Textarea placeholder fontsize html css

Tags: html, css

How do i increase textarea's placeholder font size ? i tried this and it didnt work. thanks.

```
textarea::placeholder {
  font-size: 20;
}
```

Comment: you just missed size scale. ` font-size: 20;` to   `font-size: 20px;` will work.

Answer (score 10):

You forgot the `px` at the end. That is very important. For example, how does it know if you want `px` or `em`?

View [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/does-omitting-the-px-matter/53969) for more information.

```css
textarea::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="yes"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this:

```
/* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
::placeholder { 
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

/* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

/* Microsoft Edge */
::-ms-input-placeholder { 
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

I haven't tested it with `textarea::placeholder` though, kindly try it on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You missed unit like `px`, `em`, or `rem`. Try this one.

```
textarea::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add scale size please it will fix your problem.**

---

font-size: 20px;